# Spring placeholder format

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

This is syntax which is working

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

This is alternative format which is NOT working

```
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

Any ideas why? I will always crach on tests while building.

Application properties file contains just this
   hibernate.show.sql   = false
   hibernate.format.sql = true

Comment: What version of spring are you using.  In spring 3.1 and above the <context:property-placeholder added a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer instead of a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: I am using 3.12 or above. But my question is about syntax itself...

Comment: The exact snippet that you posted for `context:property-placeholder` works perfectly for me.

Comment: @ach the op asked riddle like duplicate questions, both with misleading titles to confuse visitors from the internet, didn't bother to provide the exception stack trace or explain what behavior he expected - this kind of questions is the dark side of SO. Btw Manuel has given the correct answer in comment.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov `property-placeholder` should work in any version of Spring >= 2.5, though.

Comment: @ach yes, that is possible, but we are not telepaths :D

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks correct.  Do you have the `context` namespace registered in your context file?

For example:

```
<beans ...
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: Yes. All is working till i change that syntax of placeholder. That is the mystery... I am just going to look into Maven Logs...