# context:property-placeholder does not work

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I was tasked by relative simple tast but i got stuck at this point. My question is

Are these two syntaxes equal?

A

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

B

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

AppContext

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"
>
```

And result is here

```
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 3):

In the version of Spring 3.1(which is referenced in your xml schema) they are not quite equal

`context:property-placeholder` will define an instance of the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` 
while you have declared a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` instance with the bean declaration.

That is why sometimes it's reasonable to use the tags instead of the direct bean declarations(i.e. define *what* is done instead of *how* it's done) .

From PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  javadoc:

> As of Spring 3.1, PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer should be used
>   preferentially over this implementation; it is more flexible through
>   taking advantage of the Environment and PropertySource mechanisms also
>   made available in Spring 3.1.
>
> Prior to Spring 3.1, the  namespace
>   element registered an instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. It
>   will still do so if using the spring-context-3.0.xsd definition of the
>   namespace. That is, you can preserve registration of
>   PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer through the namespace, even if using
>   Spring 3.1; simply do not update your xsi:schemaLocation and continue
>   using the 3.0 XSD.

Comment: @Martin add the full exception stack trace!111 (maybe to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567083/spring-placeholder-format)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same.

As per the [context namespace documentation](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd)

> "OVERRIDE" indicates placeholders should be resolved first against system properties and then against any local properties

As per the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE)

> Check system properties first, before trying the specified properties. This allows system properties to override any other property source.